# Find the MGF of a bivariate random variable

Tags: probability

I have $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(1+xy(x^2-y^2))$ over $|x|\leq 1, |y|\leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise as the pdf of the random variable $(X,Y)$ and I would like to find the MGF of this random variable.

So for a bivariate MGF, I understand that if $M(t_1, t_2)$ is its MGF, then

$M(t)=E(e^{t_1x+t_2y})=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1e^{t_1x+t_2y}\frac{1}{4}(1+xy(x^2-y^2))dxdy$

Then the problem occurs that while integrating this (rather lengthy and tedious) integral, I'm dividing by the two t's which I think implies that the MGF doesn't exist when I know it does.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Is the PDF over $[-1 \times 1] \times [-1 \times 1]$ (i.e., $-1 < x, y < 1$)?

Comment: Sorry @Clarinetist I forgot to put in the limits I'll do it now but yes it is

Comment: As I understand, you have no problem with the integration. Just note that the MGF exists in a neighborhood of zero, which is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

General rule: I always recommend isolating $x$ and $y$ variables as much as possible. Assume $A = [-1, 1] \times [-1, 1]$, so that $\displaystyle\int_{A} = \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}$.

Notice that
$$\begin{align}
M(t_1, t_2) = \mathbb{E}[e^{Xt_1 + Yt_2}] &= \int_{A}e^{t_1x+t_2y}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)[1+xy(x^2-y^2)]\text{ d}y \text{ d}x \\
&= \overbrace{\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{A}e^{t_1x+t_2y}\text{ d}y \text{ d}x}^{B}+\overbrace{\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{A}e^{t_1x+t_2y}xy(x^2-y^2)\text{ d}y \text{ d}x}^{C}
\end{align}$$
Now $$\begin{align}
B &= \dfrac{1}{4}\int_{A}e^{t_1x+t_2y}\text{ d}y \text{ d}x \\
&= \dfrac{1}{4}\left[\int_{-1}^{1}e^{t_1x}\text{ d}x\right]\left[\int_{-1}^{1}e^{t_2y}\text{ d}y\right] \\
&= \dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{1}{t_1}\right)(e^{t_1}-e^{-t_1})\left(\dfrac{1}{t_2}\right)(e^{t_2}-e^{-t_2}) \\
&= \dfrac{(e^{t_1}-e^{-t_1})(e^{t_2}-e^{-t_2})}{4t_1t_2}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
C &= \dfrac{1}{4}\int_{A}e^{t_1x+t_2y}xy(x^2-y^2)\text{ d}y \text{ d}x\\
&= \dfrac{1}{4}\int_{A}\left(x^3e^{t_1x}ye^{t_2y} - xe^{t_1x}y^3e^{t_2y} \right)\text{ d}y \text{ d}x \\
&= \dfrac{1}{4}\int_{A}x^3e^{t_1x}ye^{t_2y}\text{ d}y \text{ d}x - \dfrac{1}{4}\int_{A}xe^{t_1x}y^3e^{t_2y} \text{ d}y \text{ d}x \\
&= \dfrac{1}{4}\left[\int_{-1}^{1}x^3e^{t_1x}\text{ d}x \right]\left[\int_{-1}^{1}ye^{t_2y}\text{ d}y \right] - \dfrac{1}{4}\left[ \int_{-1}^{1}xe^{t_1x}\text{ d}x\right] \left[\int_{-1}^{1}y^3e^{t_2y}\text{ d}y \right]\text{.}
\end{align}$$
We can reduce the problem of solving for $C$ to two general integrals (I prefer [tabular integration](http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/187/tabular.pdf) for this problem - short version: derivatives on left column, antiderivatives on second column):
$$\begin{align}
&\int z^3 e^{kz}\text{ d}z = \dfrac{e^{kz}}{k}z^3 - \dfrac{3e^{kz}}{k^2}z^2 + \dfrac{6e^{kz}}{k^3}z - \dfrac{6e^{kz}}{k^4} = g(z, k)\\
&\int z e^{kz}\text{ d}z = \dfrac{e^{kz}}{k}z - \dfrac{e^{kz}}{k^2} = h(z, k)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
So, 
$$C = \dfrac{1}{4}\left[g(1, t_1) - g(-1, t_1)\right]\left[h(1, t_2) - h(-1, t_2)\right]- \dfrac{1}{4}\left[h(1, t_1) - h(-1, t_1)\right]\left[g(1, t_2) - g(-1, t_2)\right]\text{.}$$
Notice that $$g(z, k) = e^{kz}\left(\dfrac{z^3}{k} - \dfrac{3z^2}{k^2}+\dfrac{6z}{k^3} - \dfrac{6}{k^4} \right)$$
and
$$h(z, k) = e^{kz}\left(\dfrac{z}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k^2} \right)$$
so that
$$\begin{align}
&g(1, k) = e^{k}\left(\dfrac{1}{k} - \dfrac{3}{k^2}+\dfrac{6}{k^3}-\dfrac{6}{k^4}  \right) \\
&g(-1, k) = e^{-k}\left(\dfrac{-1}{k} - \dfrac{3}{k^2}-\dfrac{6}{k^3}-\dfrac{6}{k^4}\right) \\
&g(1, k) - g(-1, k) = \dfrac{1}{k}(e^{k}-e^{-k})-\dfrac{3}{k^2}(e^{k}+e^{-k})+\dfrac{6}{k^3}(e^{k}-e^{-k}) - \dfrac{6}{k^4}(e^{k}+e^{-k}) \\
&\qquad \qquad\qquad\space\space\space\space\space\space= \left(\dfrac{1}{k}+\dfrac{6}{k^3}\right)(e^{k}-e^{-k})-\left(\dfrac{3}{k^2}+\dfrac{6}{k^4}\right)(e^{k}+e^{-k}) \\
&h(1, k) = e^{k}\left(\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k^2}\right) \\
&h(-1, k) = -e^{-k}\left(\dfrac{1}{k}+\dfrac{1}{k^2}\right) \\
&h(1, k) - h(-1, k) = \dfrac{1}{k}(e^{k}-e^{-k})-\dfrac{1}{k^2}(e^{k}+e^{-k})\text{.}
\end{align}$$
At this point, the multiplication is tedious, but doable.